# Why do my cats keep bringing me things to my house door when I sleep?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-education-edition

I have 4 Minecraft cats and everytime I sleep (yes, this is single player) one will sleep on my bed with me, which is normal, but some nights I'll get something at my door. It's weird because I leave my door closed, there's no way for the cats to get out, and there are no escapes. It only happens when all of them are unsitted and at night when I'm sleeping. I've gotten the following at the door:

- Phantom membrane
- 3x Rotten flesh
- 2x Rabbit feet
- Cooked rabbit meat
- Feather
- Rabbit hide

Does anyone know what's going on? I'm really confused. My world settings are on *creative mode, education edition.

[image: i keep everything my cats have given to me in this barrel.]

I keep everything the cats have given me in that barrel, I'm not sure which cat gives me the items.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please, consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Because it's their intended behaviour.

When the player sleeps, tamed cats move toward their owner and sleep near them. There is a 70% chance for a tamed cat to give the player a gift after they wake up, but only if the player sleeps at night. If a player has multiple standing tamed cats in the area, only the tamed cat that sleeps on the player may provide a gift.

This is what items you can get:

[image]

More information [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cat#Gifts).

Answer (score 1):

This is just an easter egg Mojang put into the game so that Minecraft cats brought dead animals to you. In particular, the phantom membranes are very useful because you can use them for potions of slow falling and to repair an elytra.

Phantom- Phantom membrane

Zombie- Rotten flesh

Rabbit- Rabbit feet, Cooked rabbit meat, Rabbit hide

Chicken- Feather